# How to solve this summation of ceiling function in BUILD-MAX-HEAP algorithm

Tags: heaps, heap-sort

I am stuck on solving this problem and cannot understand how is the ceiling function omitted or solved.
Please help.

The equation:

$\sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor} \lceil\frac{n}{2^{h+1}}\rceil O(h) $.

But this transformed to:

$O\left(n \sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor} \frac{h}{2^h}\right)$

My question concerns on omitting the ceiling function. I'm not clear on whether it was omitted or solved.

This has been taken from CLRS Section $6.3$ **Building a Heap**.

Please help me out.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor} \left\lceil\frac{n}{2^{h+1}}\right\rceil O(h) 
&<
\sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor} \left(1+ \frac{n}{2^{h+1}}\right) O(h)  \\
&<
\sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor} \left(\frac{n}{2^h} + \frac{n}{2^h}\right) O(h) 
=
2n \sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor} \frac{ O(h) }{2^h}
= O\left(n \sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor} \frac{ h }{2^h}\right).
\end{align*}
$$.

Comment: Thank you. I understood it. Please upvote my question if it's suitable.

Comment: Could you please let me know how inequality replaced with equality.

Comment: The equal sign refers to the last term on the first row. I'm just writing $\frac{n}{2^h} + \frac{n}{2^h}$ as $2 \frac{n}{2^h}$ and gathering the factors that do not depend on $h$.

Comment: $\sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor} \lceil\frac{n}{2^{h+1}}\rceil O(h) = O\left(n \sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor} \frac{ h }{2^h}\right).$ Just curious on knowing how is inequality replaced with an equal to.

Comment: If $f(x) \le g(x)$ and $g(x) = O(h(x))$ this also means that $f(x) = O(h(x))$. In this context $g(x) = O(h(x))$ and $f(x) = O(h(x))$ are (quite common) abuses of notation for $g(x) \in O(h(x))$ and $f(x) \in O(h(x))$, respectively. I don't know if this answers your question.

Comment: Does that mean that all the inequalities $\lt$ should be replaced with $\le$. Sorry for clarifying my doubts. But there are no teachers to guide me at the moment. Still thank you for clarifying my doubts.

Comment: I'm still not completely sure what you are asking. All the inequalities are correct. I have changed the position of the line break to make it less confusing. Is it clearer now?

Comment: In particular, when the book writes  $\sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor \lg n \rfloor} \lceil \frac{n}{2^{h+1}} \rceil O(h) = O( n \sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor \lg n \rfloor} \frac{h}{2^h}  )$, you should interpret it as: $\forall f(h) \in O(h)$ it holds that $\sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor \lg n \rfloor} \lceil \frac{n}{2^{h+1}} \rceil f(h) \in O( n \sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor \lg n \rfloor} \frac{h}{2^h}   )$.

Comment: I hope this gets you to the point I wish to clarify. $\sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor} \lceil\frac{n}{2^{h+1}}\rceil O(h) = O\left(n \sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor} \frac{ h }{2^h}\right)$. But the inequality seemed to be: $\sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor} \lceil\frac{n}{2^{h+1}}\rceil O(h) \le \sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor} \left(\frac{n}{2^h} + \frac{n}{2^h}\right) O(h)$ .

Comment: Solving this we got the answer but shouldnt this be expressed as an inequality i.e: $\le$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106474/discussion-between-steven-and-sachin-bahukhandi).